# Do Microsoft Edge and Google Chrome share cookies and sessions?

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-edge, cookies

I have been experiencing this issue lately: I logout from a website on Chrome, I am also logged out on Edge. Similarly, if I login on same website with one account on Edge and another account on Chrome, my sessions are merged after restarting the browser(s).

This is something happening from late January 2022 or early February 2022. Is this intentional? Can I prevent this from happening?

- Windows 10 Pro 21H2
- Google Chrome Version 98.0.4758.82
- Microsoft Edge Version 98.0.1108.56

Comment: Turn off Sync in both Edge and Chrome and see if that works. I do not see any sharing here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is some BS feature that imports and syncs settings on every start up and it can be turned on by default.

To disable it go

```
Settings -> Profiles -> Import browser data -> Import browser data on each launch -> Turn off
```

More: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftedge/forum/all/edge-is-sharing-chrome-site-logins-how-do-i/8016650c-847f-46f4-8a64-47d50ed29ad7?page=4